# Refresh function for one section (li) on Website

Tags: javascript, html, web, refresh

I would like to enable refresh only for one section on my website. Like for only one table cell or for one `<li>` element. Is it possible?

```
<div id="loading">
  <h1 class="name"> Loading... </h1>
  <ul class="status">
    <li>Status: </li>
    <li>loading state</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to refresh "loading state". This is a value I get from my plc. I would like to refresh this section every 3s.

I was trying to do so with JavaScript, but I had no success.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: How do you get the data from the plc?

Comment: What changes you pic and how?

Comment: @mplungjan siemens plc has webserver function. The html site is running threw this webserver. There you can read and write different stats of plc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` and inside the callback function make necessary change to update the dom content of the section.

Use `setInterval` if you want to refresh at regular interval or `setTimeout` if you need to refresh only once

```js
setInterval(() => {

  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200)
}, 5000)
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <h1 class="name" id='test'> Loading... </h1>
  <ul class="status">
    <li>Status: </li>
    <li>loading state</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How does that access the plc ?

Comment: @mplungjan **This is a value I get from my plc.**. Seem SO user is already able to access it

Comment: Unless the complete page comes from the plc, in which case OP needs to ajax or proxy ajax it to only update part of the page

Comment: @brk your code seems to be what I'm looking for, but I dont get where I have to place my variable.
Right now you just added a random number, to show that it changes (I guess)
My Variable that I get from my plc is: "loading state". That is the one I want to refresh.
It should look like this:
Status:
State 1 "3 sec refresh"
State 2

Answer (score 0):

Try `XMLHttpRequest`

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

setInterval(() => {

  xhr.open("POST", "./Add_address_of_content/", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4 || xhr.status != 200) return;
    document.getElementById('loadingDivId')=req.responseText;
  };

}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <h1 class="name" id='test'> Loading... </h1>
  <ul class="status">
    <li>Status: </li>
    <li id="loadingDivId">loading state</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```